# building fails due new library added on my app, conflicts dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, react-native

After installing new library onesignal on my react native using **npm install --save react-native-onesignal**
then I get the folloring Error while building the app:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

I know there is some conflicts between **com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1** and **com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0** with this library I added but I just dont know what is causing the conflict and how do I fix this.

the new gradle added by onesignal library looks as:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"

    compile('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.8.3') {
        // Exclude com.android.support(Android Support library) as the version range starts at 26.0.0
        //    This is due to compileSdkVersion defaulting to 23 which cant' be lower than the support library version
        //    And the fact that the default root project is missing the Google Maven repo required to pull down 26.0.0+
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        // Keeping com.google.android.gms(Google Play services library) as this version range starts at 10.2.1
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

this is how app.build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
  compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
  apt 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  compile "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  compile "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  compile 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  compile 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
  compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
  compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'



  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:26.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
  } 
}
```

ANy idea how to fix?

Comment: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0 where this is coming from, idk!

Comment: com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1  is v7, and com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0  is v4   try changing the version manually . similar to cardView version.

Comment: how do I change it manually?

Comment: none of those are on my dependencies app.build.gradle! how am I suppose to change those?

Comment: You've added there is conflict among those two in your question. Anyways try removing unnecessary dependencies, sometimes it works.

Comment: how to remove unnecessary depenencies and how do I know they are unncecessary for the app?

Comment: i dont know where this Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1)  is and what it is so that need to be changed to other version.... is there anything that I can do from dependencies ? if so could you provide some sample?

Comment: You've to check and analyse for what purpose u've added it. If you're not sure take internet's help.

Comment: I havent added those, its all react native stuff, i havent even touched it anything, what do u mean by internet? isnt stackoverflow right place for this?

Comment: everything works fine if i remove compile project(':react-native-onesignal')

Answer (score 0):

1. Change all your support library versions to `26.1.0`
2. Play services versions to `15.0.0`

and it should work.